# How to development Go App using WSL Ubuntu Bash in Win 10

Tags: ubuntu, go, windows-subsystem-for-linux, goland

I have a Windows 10 with WSL Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, I can't to install Linux on my Laptop by problems of compatibility.

The issue I see going is where to keep my GOPATH (Golang workspace) and all src code. One of the main limitations with WSL is that you cannot modify files from the linux subsystem within Windows, so keeping my GOPATH under the linux subsystem and editing using Goland or VS Code on Windows won't work.

Answer (score 3):

> I keep the GOPATH in Windows, e.g. D:\go, and then that's accessible via /mnt/d/go under WSL. I use two Go versions, one installed on Windows and one on WSL, and each environment uses their own version.

The workaround implemented in my Alienware:

```
 - Install WSL Ubuntu (go1.12.4 linux/amd64), JetBrains GoLand 2019.1 x64

 - Configure the GOPATH in Ubuntu:
    export GOPATH=/mnt/d/dev/golang_ws

 - Configure the Project Goland in the folder: "D:\dev\golang_ws"

 - Build and Test the Golang application in WSL Ubuntu, using Ubuntu Bash.
or 
 -  IntelliJ IDEA uses cmd.exe in the terminal view by default. To replace it with the Ubuntu bash, open up the IntelliJ IDEA settings menu located under “File”  > Settings > Tools > Terminal >
   Start directory : D:/dev/golang_ws
   Shell Path : C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe
   Tab Name: Local
```

Answer (score 1):

> The issue I see going is where to keep my GOPATH (Golang workspace) and all src code. One of the main limitations with WSL is that you cannot modify files from the linux subsystem within Windows, so keeping my GOPATH under the linux subsystem and editing using Goland or VS Code on Windows won't work.

What I do is the exact opposite.

I keep the GOPATH in Windows, e.g. `D:\go`, and then that's accessible via `/mnt/d/go` under WSL. I use two Go versions, one installed on Windows and one on WSL, and each environment uses their own version.

This allows me to use GoLand for all the editing needs and I can use the built-in terminal (Alt+F12) to use the WSL prompt when needed.

Comment: Good output, I been reached similar option below